# how to center both image and button? and how do i make a similar div right below it?

Tags: html, css

i am doing a school project and i'm stuck here. how do i center the image and the button on the page? i need to make 3/4 of these directly underneath each other. how do i do that? I have tried text-align and to position it but it seems to be stuck. also, do you know why my image disappears when the window is resized? thank you!

html:

```
        <div class="container">
            <img src="images/parken.jpg" alt="park" width="500px">
            <button class="btn">lokationer</button>
        </div>
    </main><!-- .content -->
```

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    position: inherit;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: inherit
}

.container .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: 0 auto` to center `display: block` elements

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="images/me.jpg" align="center" alt="park" width="500px">
    <button class="btn">lokationer</button>
</div>`
```

and for CSS, use this:

```
.container {
    border: 1pt solid red;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.container .btn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
 <div class="container">
        <img  src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="park" width="100px">
        <button class="btn">lokationer</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img  src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="park" width="100px">
        <button class="btn">lokationer</button>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
    .container {
            text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
      
     .btn {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 12px 24px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .btn:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hrfadvyn/2/